# What is the best package for generating dynamic graphs with PHP?

Tags: php, graph, gd, imagemagick, pear

I have a strong need to start implementing database driven graphs on a couple of projects and the only library I have really played with is PEAR's Image_Graph.  On the surface this seems fairly limited and like it may not be the best solution.  I am going to need to generate both bar/pie charts, nothing overly fancy for the first cut.

Does anybody have any strong feelings about any of the image/graph libraries out there for PHP?  Whether you like GD/Imagick/Image_Graph, please give a couple reasons as to why you feel this way.

Thanks!

- Nicholas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pChart: http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

I've personally used this, it works great.

Comment: Great package Luca, I have already got pie charts rendering to both screen/file using data from a table in PostgreSQL.  Thank you again!

Comment: Just as a follow-up, pChart is a great package but I have found that FusionCharts (http://www.fusioncharts.com/) is by far and away superior.  Substantially better performance and much "prettier" graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jpGraph - seems decent enough if a bit "old school".